# pass array of string between activities without using Intent or bundle

Tags: android, arrays

Want to pass array of string between activities without using Intent or Bundle in android.
How can I do this?

I have tried this for string.

In the first activity I have declared a string:

```
String str="abc"; // in activity1.java
```

And in the second activity am accessing it using this piece of code :

```
String str2=activity1.str; // in activity2.java
```

And this works fine. But how to pass array of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the problem to use array of string instead String?

Your scheme:

> in the first activity i have declared a string
>
> `String str="abc"; // in activity1.java`
>
> and in the second activity am accessing it using this piece of code
>
> `String str2=activity1.str; // in activity2.java`

Maybe just try it (in your case):

> in the first activity i have declared a string
>
> `String[] arrayStr = {"abc", "xyz"}; // in activity1.java`
>
> and in the second activity am accessing it using this piece of code
>
> `String arrayStr2 = activity1.arrayStr; // in activity2.java`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a static array in a separate class or a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass it as an intent, a possible solution would be a singleton class that contains the values you need.

```
public class MyDataHolder
{
    private static MyDataHolder instance;
    String str;
    String[] myStringArray;
    public static MyDataHolder getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new MyDataHolder();
        }
        return instance;

    }

 private MyDataHolder()
{
  myStringArray=new String[yourStringSize];
}

 public String getStringArray()
    {
        return myStringArray;
    }

    public void setStringArray(String[] str)
    {
        this.myStringArray= myStringArray;
    }

public String getStr()
    {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str)
    {
        this.str= str;
    }

}
```

Then in your actvities declare the instance variable like so

```
MyDataHolder dataHolder = MyDataHolder.getInstance();
dataHolder.getStr();
dataHolder.setStr("");
```

Since its a Singleton, the data in the class will be shared.

Comment: do i have to pass anything in that dataholder.setstr(" "); ?

Comment: Its a mutator function, if you want to change the value of the string pass, it a value. If you don't want to change the value, you don't need to use that function

Comment: Just realized you were asking for a string array, edited code to show it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Here is a snippet I tried.

In the first activity I declared an array as static with public specifier:

Activity1.java

```
public static String[] activity1_arr={'abc','efg','hij'}; // sample data. in my application am fetching it from database.
```

In second activity I accessed it using the activity name with array

Activity2.java

```
String[] activity2_arr; // declaring array
activity_arr=Activity1.activity1_arr // accessing the array with class
```

And this did the trick.